# How to compare date with current date in php

Tags: php, mysql

I stored expiry date field as var char datatype in MySQL table. Now i need to compare expiry date with current date. How to convert var char datatype as date in php coding and compare date in select query where condition.

Comment: php has date_diff() function. Use that

Comment: You should use a datetime datatype instead of a varchar. Then you can do this directly in mysql.

Comment: But i stored my date in varchar datatype

Answer (score 1):

why don't you do it in the query itself.

```
$current_date=date("Y-m-d");
mysql_query("select * from your_table where STR_TO_DATE(expiry_date,'%Y-%M-%D')>'".$date."');
```

or

You can do it in php itself

```
if(strtotime($current_date) > strtotime($row['date'])) { 
     //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE start_date <= CURDATE() AND end_date >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: The OP said that the date in in a varchar, not in a date column.